# How Object repository works and how is it faster?

Tags: qtp

In QTP, there is an object repository which stores objects. And these objects can be reused. What does reuse mean here? Is that object kept in memory?....The object repository is just an xml file which stores the properties if an object, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object repository can be thought of as a repository of object descriptions, rather than a repository of the objects themselves. QTP uses the object repository to identify runtime objects, based on characteristics you have specified. When you first record some actions, only the default identification characteristics are stored. You can modify these as needed, for example if an object fails to be correctly identified at runtime.
You are correct in stating that the repository is actually ("behind the scenes") simply an XML structure which makes it possible to look at it in an editor.
The "reuse" that is referred to means that from different tests, you can refer to the same object repository and you won't have to go through the work of identifying and adding objects to your test repository. An example could be two tests which make use of a data table in a web application. Instead of creating two test-specific repositories, you could just create one shared repository and use the data table description contained in it to drive both test interactions with this table.
There is a second method which you could use to identify objects at runtime: regular expressions. These are probably less flexible when it comes to designing large tests or sets of tests as maintainability does become an issue; however - they tend to be, IMHO, a bit faster than using the object repository.
A code example:

```
If Browser(“hwnd:=“ & browserTitle).Page(“url:=“ & pageUrl).Exist(0) then
   'Do something...
End If
```

You could have added the browser object to the repository, or just identified it using the above code. Descriptive programming is an alternative, but should be used sparingly and mostly around checkpoints. In fact, you can actually use regular expressions in object identification properties in the repository, but that's a different story. Let me know if you need more info around that.

Hope this helps to give you an overview.

Answer (score 1):

Objects can be reused means you can use the objects that are stored in the object repository across one or more tests and one or more times in the same test.

E.g: Say you have a **login** page that is shared by 2 applications (and you are maintaining 2 different test scripts for these two applications). 
This page has Username, Password and Application Name fields.

So the object in the object repository (Login_Page (parent object) and Username, Password and Application_Name (child objects)) can be shared by the scripts for the 2 different applications.

Objects are stored as part of test (in **.mtr** format - available only to the containing script) and shared object repository (**.tsr** format - available to any script it is associated with). So in fact it is stored on local system or Quality Center or a shared network path.

Object repository is stored in a proprietary format (.mtr or .tsr) and can be exported to xml format.

Contrary to what many websites mention, speed of object access form object repository quite comparable with other methods (like using Set method, Descriptive programming etc). The time taken to access object depends on the 'depth' of the object in repository.

Say the hierarchy is Browser > Page > Frame > Field1, Field2 ... .

No matter how many Browser objects are there, the time taken to access *n*th Browser object remains nearly flat (It is '*0 level deep*'. Page is '*1 level deep*'). Same holds good for its child objects.

I have found that the time difference to set a value (say a WebEdit box) using descriptive programming and object repository is of the order of ~2 seconds over 100 iterations (descriptive prog being faster).

And moreover none of the official documentation available for QTP mentions that script execution script is affected as the repository size grows. (I have tested this with a repository size of 194KB and 38.5MB).

Answer (score 0):

the use of the term `regular expressions` is erroneous, he means `descriptive programming` and in this option you are exchanging exceptionally faster test execution for considerably slower and more difficult maintenance.